# Can a Source Generator tell if its being run for editor support (IntelliSense) or as part of an actual build?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, sourcegenerators

My source generator needs to write some files to disk in addition to generating code files for the compilation in progress. These disk writes are completely unnecessary when the generator is being run by the IDE for its IntelliSense (or equivalent) functionality and only makes sense when the project is being actually built (it even tends to cause some failures, the IDE loves to run multiple instances of the source generator simultaneously).

Additionally, I see no reason to generate actual internals of any of the types generated by the source generator. Intuitively, only generating the public surface for the generated types would be lead to a faster and more responsive editor experience.

What is the most robust way for the source generator to differentiate what purpose it is being run for?

Comment: You could consider using `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`.  For builds, it's going to be `MSBuild.exe`, for Intellisense it will return null because VS is ultimately not a managed executable.  If it ever becomes one, it'll still be a different assembly than `MSBuild.exe`.  Not sure if there's a better technique, but it's the only one that comes to mind.

Comment: @KirkWoll I explicitly asked for "most robust way", I'm already doing it using entry assembly name. And it is not msbuild.exe. According to my experiments "VBCSCompiler" (for builds using IDE) or "csc" (for builds using dotnet) seems to be reliable. But I fully expect different IDEs or future versions of dotnet to behave differently.

Comment: I was just trying to be helpful, and brainstorm solutions, dude.  You didn't mention things you tried.

Comment: @KirkWoll My apologies if my reply came out rude, didn't mean it that way.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't give you a way to ask "am I in the IDE?" since that isn't always the correct question. For example:

> Additionally, I see no reason to generate actual internals of any of the types generated by the source generator. Intuitively, only generating the public surface for the generated types would be lead to a faster and more responsive editor experience.

That's correct, up until you are doing Hot Reload/Edit and Continue, and we need those full implementations in the IDE process as were updating the debugee process. Now, that might not be workable in your particular scenario, but you get the idea.

What we have been trying to do instead is give a better way to give hints of intent. An incremental generator can call [RegisterImplementationSourceOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.incrementalgeneratorinitializationcontext.registerimplementationsourceoutput?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.2.0) which is our hint to only run that if we need implementations. At the moment of this writing and in VS 17.2 we are still running that in the IDE, but we'll hopefully fix that soon.

There's also still some work in the pipeline: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/57589 is tracking adding an API to do the reverse, and https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/49935 for a way to write other files directly.

Comment: Thank you for an authoritative answer. I have indeed not considered edit&continue, but that is not a functionality we can use due to other constraints anyway (admittedly, having to generate everything with T4 was one of them...). Is there any reason why the intent functionality is being worked on for incremental generators only? Those drive up complexity of the generator a lot, and seem to sometimes have very limited benefit (for example, I need to run protoc to compile a gRPC interface in the background - that needs to be recompiled entirely every time).

Comment: Frankly we're only investing in the incremental generator API at this point; had we figured out the design for that early enough we might have never shipped the first API!